# jQuery problemas de etiqueta de imágenes y de enlaces en un variable de texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Problemas con una variable de texto donde deseo guardar etiquetas de imagen y de enlace.

```
a qui esta el código completo y correjido el ; que faltaba y aun me muestra el error al presionar el botón.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="chuchito" type="button" >Aprietame!</button>
<div id="contenido"></div>
<div id="acciones"></div>
<script>
prueba();

function prueba()

  {
  var d="/";
  var html="";
  var cuerpom="";

  cuerpom+="<img src='pollito.png' style='width: 100%;' >"; /// Aqui 
  cuerpom+="<br><b>Reseña:</b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Fuente:</b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Autor: </b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Tipo:</b>  Bla..bla..";
  cuerpom+="<br><b>Eje:</b>Bla..Bla..<br><b>Duración:</b>Bla..Bla.";
  cuerpom+="<a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank'></a>"; /// Aqui tambien

  html+="<script>";
  html+="$('#chuchito').click(function() { ";
  html+="$('#contenido').html('"+cuerpom+"');";
  html+="});";
  html+="<"+d+"script>";


  $("#acciones").html(html);
  }

</script>


</body>
<html>
```

Esto es lo que muestra la consola de Google Chrome

```
> VM346:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at p (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Ja (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at T (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.html (jquery.min.js:3)
    at prueba ((index):33)
    at (index):12
p @ jquery.min.js:2
Ja @ jquery.min.js:3
append @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
T @ jquery.min.js:3
html @ jquery.min.js:3
prueba @ (index):33
(anonymous) @ (index):12
```

Comment: Todo ese código es javascript, no tendría nada que ver con tu error de tu consola java. En que momento salta ese error? al usar alguna funcionalidad o al desplegar??

Comment: a qui esta el código completo y correjido el ; que faltaba y aun me muestra el error al presionar el botón

Comment: publica el codigo de '#chuchito'

Comment: Madre mía W****... Porqué haces esto: `html+="<"+d+"script>";` ? Porqué mejor no haces: `html+="</script>";`?

Comment: Tu objetivo es que al hacer click en el botón, se agregue en el `div` "acciones" la imagen y el link? es correcto?

Comment: Si es correcto, que se agrege la imagen el enlace y el texto

Comment: "Porqué mejor no haces: html+="</script>";?" por que me marca error la consola

Comment: @jemonge prueba el código como propones y te darás cuenta que el navegador muestra el botón y debajo del mismo "$("#acciones").html(html); }"; por eso la diagonal la guarde en la variable d="/";

Comment: @FabianVazquezGomez tienes razón. Debería ser  `html+="<\/script>";` para que funcione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás teniendo un problema con las comillas. Si cambias las comillas en la variable `cuerpom`, el problema se soluciona:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="chuchito" type="button" >Aprietame!</button>
<div id="contenido"></div>
<div id="acciones"></div>
<script>
prueba();

function prueba()

  {
  var d="/";
  var html="";
  var cuerpom="";

  cuerpom+='<img src="pollito.png" style="width: 100%;" >'; /// Aqui 
  cuerpom+='<br><b>Reseña:</b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Fuente:</b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Autor: </b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Tipo:</b>  Bla..bla..';
  cuerpom+='<br><b>Eje:</b>Bla..Bla..<br><b>Duración:</b>Bla..Bla.';
  cuerpom+='<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>'; /// Aqui tambien
  
  html+="<script>";
  html+="$('#chuchito').click(function() { ";
  html+="$('#contenido').html('"+cuerpom+"');";
  html+="});";
  html+="<"+d+"script>";


  console.log(html);
  
  $("#acciones").html(html);
  }

</script>


</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Jemonge , ¡Así ya funciono!

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma con el mismo fin:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="chuchito" type="button" >Aprietame!</button>
<div id="contenido"></div>
<div id="acciones"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#chuchito').click(function() {
 var cuerpom="";
 cuerpom+="<img src='pollito.png' style='width: 100%;' >"; /// Aqui 
 cuerpom+="<br><b>Reseña:</b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Fuente:</b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Autor: </b>Bla..bla..<br><b>Tipo:</b>  Bla..bla..";
 cuerpom+="<br><b>Eje:</b>Bla..Bla..<br><b>Duración:</b>Bla..Bla.";
 cuerpom+="<a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank'></a>"; /// Aqui tambien 
 $('#contenido').html(cuerpom);
    });  
});
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Gracias @juliocpiro , Es que realice, a sí la pregunta por que es de un código mas complejo donde genero dinamicamente a "Chuchito" y sus hermanos, por eso necesito escribir su acción de la manera descrita por @ jemonge